# Deleting a vector element in a loop, based upon a conditional statement

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In this code snippet Update() returns a boolean, if it returns false I would like to delete the element from the vector.

However, this produces a run-time error of debug assertion failed. The expression is "vector iterator not incrementable".

**The code:**

```
for(auto iter = someVector.begin(); iter != someVector.end(); ++iter){
    if(!iter->get()->Update()) iter = someVector.erase(iter);
}
```

**I have tried subtracting from the iterator as follows too:**

```
for(auto iter = particles.begin(); iter != particles.end(); ++iter){
    if(!iter->get()->Update()) iter = --(particles.erase(iter));
}
```

...but this results in "vector iterator not decrementable".

**How can I make my code works as intended; so that the vector element is deleted when the Update() function returns false?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove elements of a vector inside the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628951/remove-elements-of-a-vector-inside-the-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the loop to this:

```
for(auto iter = someVector.begin(); iter != someVector.end();){
    if(!iter->get()->Update())
        iter = someVector.erase(iter);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

The reason for the assertion is that, after the call to `erase`, `iter` might be equal to `end()`. The iterator returned by `erase` is already "next", you're not supposed to increment it.

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you! I didn't know you could omit the last part of the for loop either.

Comment: No problem. Do read @Dietmar's answer, too! As for loop, you can omit all three statements: `for(;;) {}`. This is how some people like to write their infinite loops.

Comment: I feel educated! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend **not** using `erase()` as above in the first place but rather use it something like this:

```
someVector.erase(std::remove_if(someVector.begin(), someVector.end(),
                                [](decltype(*someVector.begin()) element){
                                    return !element.get()->update();
                                },
                 someVector.end());
```

When just one element needs to be erased it does roughly the same as using the one iterator version of `erase()`. When multiple elements need to be erased, it does less copyies/moves. Note that I use a lambda function just because it is easier to express but the same can be done with a suitable function object if lambda functions are not available.

Comment: +1 I was writing this only :D, should be `return !element.get()->update()`

Comment: Thank you, it's always nice to know more than one way to solve a problem. However, in my case I will extremely rarely need to erase more than 1 element at a time.

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard: Using the algorithm is no worse than erasing an element individually and works better in the rare case where there is more than 1 element. Thus, it is obviously the way to go! Not to mention that the algorithms could possibly wing a few extra performance improvements (e.g., suitable loop unrolling, due boundary checks just once in a debugging implementation, etc.): using `std::remove_if()` is a win!

Comment: Thanks again! I shall look into it more then, as the syntax looks rather confusing to me. If I can understand what is going on, I will use it. It's the [](decltype... that throws me. That said...google is my friend ;)

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard: This is just a C++11 lambda function and a somewhat awkward use of `decltype()` to determine the argument type. You could also use a function object like `struct predicat { template <typename T> bool operator()(T& o) { return !o.get()->Update(); } };` and then use `predicate()` instead. If the indirection via `get()` wouldn't be needed it would be easy to use `std::mem_fn()`. Using `std::bind()` to compose things would also work but would probably be more confusing...