# How to delete element in vector<type> through a reference for loop

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Hello I'm pretty new to C++ and very much so in references and pointers and am trying to remove elements in the following for loop:

```cpp
for(type &i : vectorName)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        //delete i
    }
}
```

How do I do this while making sure no null values are created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove elements of a vector inside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628951/remove-elements-of-a-vector-inside-the-loop)

Comment: `delete` element (assuming pointer so) and removing element from vector are 2 different things.

Comment: please have a look at the std algorithms https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Although one can use the address-of operator, and leverage the fact that array contents must be continuous, and thus derive the required iterator value for `erase()`, it's simpler not to use range iteration in this case, and iterate directly using pointers, making it easier to call `erase()`, when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Use nice built-in [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

```
vectorName.erase(std::remove_if(vectorName.begin(), vectorName.end(), [](const auto& i){return condition;}), 
                 vectorName.end());
```

`erase` is crucial, because `remove_if` doesn't change the size of the container. It simply returns it's new end (so that it can work with any range, not only full containers). It's called [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

---

Your approach is much more difficult to use, because erasing element from the vector **invalidates all iterators**. This means that after removing one element, you cannot continue in the same range-based loop.