# Vector subscript out of range in SFML game

Tags: c++, sfml

Im working on a game as a project for my game development course. It is using vectors to spawn enemies at the top of the screen and run down as well as creating "bullets" that are fired by both the player and the boss. After adding the boss and code for his bullets the previously working code is now throwing a vector subscript out of range error. This error is always thrown right after hitting an enemy and didn't happen before the boss was introduced.

```
            bullets[i].shape.move(bullets[i].currVelocity);

            //Bullet Removal
            if (bullets[i].shape.getPosition().x < 0 || bullets[i].shape.getPosition().x > window.getSize().x
                || bullets[i].shape.getPosition().y < 0 || bullets[i].shape.getPosition().y > window.getSize().y) {
                bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
            }
            else {
                //Collision Code
                for (size_t k = 0; k < enemies.size(); k++) {
                    if (bullets[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(enemies[k].getGlobalBounds())) {
                        bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
                        enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + k);
                        score = score + 1;
                        fiveScore = fiveScore + 1;
                        std::cout << "Score: " << score << std::endl;
                        hitSound.play();
                        if (fiveScore == 5) {
                            fiveScore = 0;
                            //scoreUpSound.play();
                        }
                        if (score >= 100 && bossSpawned == false) {
                            bossSpawned = true;
                            boss.setPosition(250.0f, 50.0f);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (bullets[i].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(boss.getGlobalBounds())) {
                    bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
                    hitSound.play();
                    bossHP = bossHP - 1;
                    if (bossHP <= 0) {
                        bossSpawned = false;
                        boss.setPosition(3214.0f, 4322.0f);
                        text.setString("You have completed your quest." "\n" "The warlock is slain and the realm is" "\n" "safe, yet as life returns to the kingdom" "\n" "you are dissatisfied. Your brother and" "\n" "lover are both deceased and" "\n" "you feel only death will heal your pain.");
                        text.setPosition(25.0f, 150.0f);
                        window.clear();
                        window.draw(text);
                        window.display();
                        Sleep(9000);
                        return 0;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code for the player's bullet collisions.

```
            b2.shape.setPosition(bossCenter);
            b2.currVelocity = bossAimDirNorm * b2.maxSpeed;

            bossbullets.push_back(BossBullet(b2));
        }

        for (size_t z = 0; z < bossbullets.size(); z++) {
            bossbullets[z].shape.move(bossbullets[z].currVelocity);

            //BossBullet Removal
            if (bossbullets[z].shape.getPosition().x < 0 || bossbullets[z].shape.getPosition().x > window.getSize().x
                || bossbullets[z].shape.getPosition().y < 0 || bossbullets[z].shape.getPosition().y > window.getSize().y) {
                bossbullets.erase(bossbullets.begin() + z);
            }
            else {
                //Collision Code
                if (bossbullets[z].shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(player.getGlobalBounds())) {
                        bossbullets.erase(bossbullets.begin() + z);
                        playerDead = true;
                        text.setString("You have failed your quest.");
                        text.setPosition(150.0f, 150.0f);
                        window.clear();
                        window.draw(text);
                        window.display();
                        Sleep(5000);
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code for the boss' bullet collisions. Any help or even ideas of what could be wrong would be helpful. Reverting to before I added the boss is the only solution I've found for now.

Comment: its not connected with crash, but if you use `bossbullets.erase(bossbullets.begin() + z);` you miss the next element. For example when `z = 4` you delete the 5-th element, then the for loop will increase the `z` variable to the 5, so the new (after delete) 5-th element will be not checked

Answer (score 1):

You are erasing from your vector while looping over it. This changes the size of your vector which can often be a source of errors.

Take a look at [Remove elements of a vector inside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628951/remove-elements-of-a-vector-inside-the-loop) for a way to do it instead.