# How did I get a segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c++, stl

```
vector<int> cutTheSticks(vector<int> arr) {
    vector<int> res;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int i=0, mini=0, c=arr.size();
    while(c>0) {
        res.push_back(c);
        mini=*min_element(arr.begin(),arr.end());
        for(i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
            arr[i]-=mini;
        }
        for(auto it=arr.begin();it!=arr.end();it++) {
            i=*it;
            if(i==0)
                arr.erase(it);
        }
        c=arr.size();
    }
    return res;
}
```

I am running this piece of code in the hackerank portal and not on any system.

Comment: `arr.erase(it);` and then `it++` ... Look at what happens with iterators when you `erase()` and also what `erase()` returns.

Comment: `while(c>0) {` I  don't see where you modify `c`.

Comment: You assign `c` before the `while(c>0) {` but never again in the loop. This will run forever, or strictly speaking, until the free memory is exceeded.

Comment: `arr.erase(it);` does that invalidate `it` ? Can you always do `it != arr.end();` and `it++;` afterwards ?

Comment: In addition to the problem of calling `arr.erase()` in the inner loop, if `arr` is ever emptied (i.e. which is possible as there are nested loops, one of which erases elements), `min_element()` will return an end iterator, so the assignment to `mini` will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Deleted my answer since there are too many unknowns...  :-)

Comment: use `it = arr.erase(it);` when erasing since the iterator becomes invalid after erasing

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `erase` is causing the problem in this case. In fact, you exactly don't need a complex approach like this for [the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks/problem).

You can simply sort the array in reverse order and then use `pop_back()` while last element is `0`. It will also help to reduce complexity as then you won't need to call `min_element` each time. You can directly use `arr.back()` for the minimum element.

***Logic behind my approach:***

In each iteration, you are subtracting minimum element from each element. This makes number(s) having the minimum value as `0`. Clearly, since the array is sorted in reverse order, these numbers will be in the end of the array. You then want to remove these elements for which `pop_back` is one of the best available options.

***Here is sample code:***

```cpp
vector<int> cutTheSticks(vector<int> arr) {
    vector<int> res;
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), greater<int>());
    while (not arr.empty()) {
        res.push_back(arr.size());
        for (auto &&i : arr)
            i -= arr.back();
        while (not (arr.back() or arr.empty()))
            arr.pop_back();
    }
    return res;
}
```

***PS:***

If you want to stick with your original algorithm then replace

```cpp
for (auto it = arr.begin(); it!=arr.end(); it++) {
    i = *it;
    if(i == 0)
        arr.erase(it);
}
```

with something like:

```cpp
arr.erase(remove(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0), arr.end()); // called as erase-remove idiom
```

or

```cpp
for (auto it = arr.begin(); it!=arr.end(); /* it++ */) {
    i = *it;
    if(i == 0)
        it = arr.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

This thread may help you: [Remove elements of a vector inside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628951/remove-elements-of-a-vector-inside-the-loop).