# making public member read only

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

```
class A{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        const int &ref = a;
};

int main() {
    A obj;
    obj.a = 20;     // error cause private
    obj.ref = 30;   // not private but const so ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a member variable accessible but read only through the interface. Currently I've tried this approach and it seems to compile fine. I made a `const reference` to my original variable `int a` and made it `public`. Is there anything that's wrong with this practice that I might be missing out? Or is this example safe and sound to use for practical purposes?

Nothing wrong with providing a member function with `const` correctness applied (and I've used that too and intend to do so always), but I'm asking is there any thing wrong with this way if I have to provide a variable that is only read-only.

Thankyou :)

Comment: What's wrong with the good old accessor function? `int A::get_a() const noexcept { return this->a; }`

Comment: The better practice is to use getters and setters to access your class members. You have more control on the access logics

Comment: Doesn't adding the `const int&` member break copy semantics for the class?

Comment: @JamesAdkison could you explain a bit on that...

Comment: @JamesAdkison Important point (another point is increasing the size of the class, needlessly)

Comment: @oopaewem `A obj1; A obj2; obj1 = obj2;` This creates 2 objects then copies 1 to the other but it won't work with a `const &` data member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        const int &ref = a;
};
```

> is there any thing wrong with this way if I have to provide a variable that is only read-only

There are at least a couple drawbacks with this design decision for class `A`.

#### 1: Class Size

Also as [Dieter Lücking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249683/dieter-l%c3%bccking) mentions in a
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906299/making-public-amember-read-only#comment57548922_34906299):

> increasing the size of the class, needlessly

#### 2: Copy Semantics

It breaks the compiler generated copy assignment operator. For example, the following code behavior is generally desirable but doesn't work.

```
A obj1;

// ...

A obj2;

// make changes to 'obj2'

// Update 'obj1' with the changes from 'obj2'
obj1 = obj2; // This copy doesn't work!
```

More information:

- [Should I prefer pointers or references in member data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data)
- [Assignment operator with reference class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635844/assignment-operator-with-reference-class-member)
- [Thinking in C++, 2nd ed. Volume 1 ©2000 by Bruce Eckel, 11: References & the Copy-Constructor](http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Chapter11.html)

> There are certain rules when using references:
>
> 1. A reference must be initialized when it is created. (Pointers can be initialized at any time.)
> 2. Once a reference is initialized to an object, it cannot be changed to refer to another object. (Pointers can be pointed to another object at any time.)
> 3. You cannot have NULL references. You must always be able to assume that a reference is connected to a legitimate piece of storage.

It may be possible to implement a custom assignment operator but that's more code to maintain (i.e., another drawback in my opinion).

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    explicit A(int value) : a(value) {}

    A& operator=(const A& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }

    const int& ref = a;
};

int main()
{
    A obj1(10);
    std::cout << "1: " << obj1.ref << "\n";

    A obj2(20);
    std::cout << "2: " << obj2.ref << "\n";

    obj1 = obj2;
    std::cout << "1: " << obj1.ref << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

The idiomatic way to address this issue is to use a proper accessor function.

```
class A {
    private:
        int a;

    public:
        int getA() const { return a; }
};
```

Comment: I just tried ideone and [found](http://ideone.com/KXlNSP) that indeed copy semantics would be broken. Could you include the reason too? Or should I post another question for them? Thanks :)

Comment: @oopaewem I updated the answer and provided some additional references.

Comment: `it may be possible to implement a custom assignment operator`: No it is impossible (only if the reference is a pointer, it would be possible, but ugly again)

Comment: @DieterLücking I didn't think it was possible either but I tried the [following](http://ideone.com/pA0CBB) and it appeared to work correctly (i.e., the custom assignment operator ignores the `const int&` data member). I've removed that comment from my answer but I'm curious why my example code seems to work?

Comment: @James Adkison I am wrong (I was thinking about non internal references). That makes the answer wrong, too

Comment: @DieterLücking I tried to delete the answer but it won't let me. How would you recommend I proceed?

Comment: @DieterLücking For now, I just tried to update the answer. Is there a way for a moderator to delete the answer?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Place a big "This is wrong, but accepted"  in your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101216/discussion-between-james-adkison-and-dieter-lucking).

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to do this in C++ is by making the actual member `private` but including a public 'getter' method for the interface, as below:

```
class A{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        int get_a() const { return a; }

        A() : a(20) {}
};

int main() {
    A obj;
    int n = obj.get_a(); // n = 20
    return 0;
}
```

The user cannot set the value of `A::a` but can use `A::get_a` to retrieve its value.

Comment: `int get_a() const;`

Comment: Initialisation list for the constructor would be better